# How to fix funny characters coming from twitter API

Tags: php, twitter, utf-8

Im using Twitter's RESTful API 1.1 and on odd occations usually when there is a URL embedded in the tweet it pulls through in funny charcters e.g.

@MyHandle_123 RT @ThinkAfricaFeed: Controversy & acrimony may surround Nigeria's country's federalist system but it may be the country's best option: httÃ¢Â€Â¦

I tried to call the function utf8_decode but its still renders funny characters in my browser.

Any idea's on how I can get the returned values to show correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a similar problem, since you tried the utf8 decode and it didn't work, try this:

> htmlentities($td->text, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');

where td is the object whose text or item is being referenced.

Hope that helps